# What does warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int] main(){ mean?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int k;
double sin() ,cos();
main(){
    float A=0, B=0, i, j, z[1760];
    char b[1760];
    printf("\x1b[2J");
    for(; ; ) {
        memset(b,32,1760);
        memset(z,0,7040);
        for(j=0; 6.28>j; j+=0.07) {
            for(i=0; 6.28 >i; i+=0.02) {
                float sini=sin(i),
                      cosj=cos(j),
                      sinA=sin(A),
                      sinj=sin(j),
                      cosA=cos(A),
                      cosj2=cosj+2,
                      mess=1/(sini*cosj2*sinA+sinj*cosA+5),
                      cosi=cos(i),
                      cosB=cos(B),
                      sinB=sin(B),
                      t=sini*cosj2*cosA-sinj* sinA;
                int x=40+30*mess*(cosi*cosj2*cosB-t*sinB),
                    y= 12+15*mess*(cosi*cosj2*sinB +t*cosB),
                    o=x+80*y,
                    N=8*((sinj*sinA-sini*cosj*cosA)*cosB-sini*cosj*sinA-sinj*cosA-cosi *cosj*sinB);
                if(22>y&&y>0&&x>0&&80>x&&mess>z[o]){
                    z[o]=mess;
                    b[o]=".,-~:;=!*#$@"[N>0?N:0];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\x1b[d");
        for(k=0; 1761>k; k++)
            putchar(k%80?b[k]:10);
        A+=0.04;
        B+= 0.02;
    }
}
```

Hi, I have been trying to get this code to work for a while but have no idea what's going on. Every time I compile it I get this warning. I tried changing it to Int Main() but that didn't work either. Its supposed to print a donut on my terminal window. Not very familiar with C so it could be a dumb mistake. Thanks in advance for your help

```
'donut.c:5:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main(){
^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: Do you see a type specifier at the place the warning refers to? Not? Add one. You might want to check a HelloWorld for the correct prototype of `main()`.

Comment: This code seems to be ancient and borderline obfuscated.  Explicitly declaring `main` returning `int` has been the norm for the last 30 years or more.  Likewise, don't include your own declarations of `sin/cos`, but instead `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: You say you tried `Int Main()` but C is case-sensitive; it needs to be `int main(void)`, lower case.

Comment: @NateEldredge That case-sensitivity issue is a contribution beyond my answer (because I missed the non-code-formatted attempt by OP....). If you make an answer it would provide more insight. Otherwise let me know whether you mind if I augment my answer with this.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler warning tells you that you did not specify a type for the return value of your `main()` function.
Because of that the compiler assumes the default `int`.
This, by sheer luck, is the correct return type for that function.
In the simplest case use

```
int main(void)
```

Comment: `double sin() ,cos();` is also nonsense and should be replaced with `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: @Lundin I agree, but decided to focus on what OP is asking about.

Comment: It's probably not "luck" but just very old code.

Comment: @NateEldredge Using very old code, which triggers ancient defaults in compilers, that is what I describe as "luck"; because I did not want to describe it as "unwise" or "wrong". ;-) The fact that the question was asked implies that OP is not aware of what is going on. So it is much more luck than "conscious decision to rely on then applicable defaults".

Comment: @Lundin: How do you figure `double sin() ,cos();` is nonsense? C 2018 7.1.4 2 says standard library functions may be manually declared.

Comment: @EricPostpischil All identifiers with external linkage in the standard libs are reserved. Also `double sin()` is an obsolete style function declaration as per future language directions. And most importantly, defining your own trigonometry library just for the heck of it is not time well spent.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, they are reserved, and the code in the question is consistent with using them in the way they are reserved. As I cited, the standard explicitly allows programs to declare standard library functions. The code in the question does not show any definition of its own trigonometry library. By appearance, it is merely calling the standard library functions. And even if declarators with empty parentheses are obsolescent (not obsolete), that does not make them “nonsense.”

Comment: @Lundin: No, it is not.